# Is there any wrong in my css selection in this web scraping code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My css selectors `response.css('div.jhfizC')` and `('a[itemprop="url"]')` show 97 items in the web page, but my code is only scraping 35 items. Where is the fault?

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class EbayfootSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'exebay'

    start_urls = ['https://www.mercari.com/search/?brandIds=4578&categoryIds=724&facets=2&length=30']


    def parse(self, response):
        big_div = response.css('div.jhfizC')
    
        for all_div in big_div:
        
            item_url = all_div.css('a[itemprop="url"]').css('::attr(href)')[0].extract()
            if item_url is not None:
                print(item_url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of the url just put length 90 instead of 30 , length indicate  30 item per page.

```
In [1]: url = 'https://www.mercari.com/search/?brandIds=4578&categoryIds=724&facets=2&length=90'                          

fetch(url)                                                                                                    
                                                                                                     
In [4]: response                                                                                                          
Out[4]: <200 https://www.mercari.com/search/?brandIds=4578&categoryIds=724&facets=2&length=90>

In [6]: big_div = response.css('div.jhfizC')                                                                              

In [7]: item_url = all_div.css('a[itemprop="url"]').css('::attr(href)')

In [11]: for i, all_div in enumerate( big_div): 
    ...:                 item_url = all_div.css('a[itemprop="url"]').css('::attr(href)')[0].extract() 
    ...:                 print(i,'https://www.mercari.com/'+item_url) 
    ...:                  
                                                                                                               
0 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m27379701884/?ref=search_results
1 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m87408459178/?ref=search_results
2 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m31639451091/?ref=search_results
3 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m55461396239/?ref=search_results
4 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m61065950216/?ref=search_results
5 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m59003878460/?ref=search_results
6 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m42114019532/?ref=search_results
7 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m60410492125/?ref=search_results
8 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m61707057858/?ref=search_results
9 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m77824553207/?ref=search_results
10 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m72401412407/?ref=search_results
11 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m83737664911/?ref=search_results
12 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m31513565581/?ref=search_results
13 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m53686770401/?ref=search_results
14 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m31687661458/?ref=search_results
15 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m73565122351/?ref=search_results
16 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m54774041977/?ref=search_results
17 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m63815616689/?ref=search_results
18 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m72900819243/?ref=search_results
19 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m38982779224/?ref=search_results
20 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m16950460012/?ref=search_results
21 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m96072811718/?ref=search_results
22 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m98926246504/?ref=search_results
23 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m22674930214/?ref=search_results
24 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m76505587116/?ref=search_results
25 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m81533546144/?ref=search_results
26 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m71881974396/?ref=search_results
27 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m57251522596/?ref=search_results
28 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m85616167131/?ref=search_results
29 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m66592587980/?ref=search_results
30 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m16222098730/?ref=search_results
31 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m30516632346/?ref=search_results
32 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m82678279409/?ref=search_results
33 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m22459472107/?ref=search_results
34 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m49112577494/?ref=search_results
35 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m89573947301/?ref=search_results
36 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m15348612036/?ref=search_results
37 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m11392827625/?ref=search_results
38 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m60718086586/?ref=search_results
39 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m57133492284/?ref=search_results
40 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m73858839710/?ref=search_results
41 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m77945239665/?ref=search_results
42 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m13356901817/?ref=search_results
43 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m63603936227/?ref=search_results
44 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m49178440576/?ref=search_results
45 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m14806568451/?ref=search_results
46 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m67151874325/?ref=search_results
47 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m90580799274/?ref=search_results
48 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m66942995364/?ref=search_results
49 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m90049596871/?ref=search_results
50 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m25892617355/?ref=search_results
51 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m11787855892/?ref=search_results
52 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m10379012995/?ref=search_results
53 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m28508818974/?ref=search_results
54 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m23474551312/?ref=search_results
55 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m99385515312/?ref=search_results
56 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m13303803841/?ref=search_results
57 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m36605382938/?ref=search_results
58 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m27122502813/?ref=search_results
59 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m58324967907/?ref=search_results
60 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m88943761510/?ref=search_results
61 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m73769298655/?ref=search_results
62 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m60815399306/?ref=search_results
63 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m48872595825/?ref=search_results
64 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m53519878176/?ref=search_results
65 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m59524853672/?ref=search_results
66 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m72346338496/?ref=search_results
67 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m86496319979/?ref=search_results
68 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m54138309188/?ref=search_results
69 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m61559200881/?ref=search_results
70 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m42596652475/?ref=search_results
71 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m54065649678/?ref=search_results
72 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m87125447888/?ref=search_results
73 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m26421150316/?ref=search_results
74 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m72992367701/?ref=search_results
75 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m46688464169/?ref=search_results
76 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m34842804531/?ref=search_results
77 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m80806378583/?ref=search_results
78 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m39280119583/?ref=search_results
79 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m48130903632/?ref=search_results
80 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m57955016021/?ref=search_results
81 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m54360880136/?ref=search_results
82 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m29432458124/?ref=search_results
83 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m81313993828/?ref=search_results
84 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m34469644752/?ref=search_results
85 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m26953235217/?ref=search_results
86 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m29197336718/?ref=search_results
87 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m24460351728/?ref=search_results
88 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m95427865100/?ref=search_results
89 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m29184483225/?ref=search_results
90 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m47761827365/?ref=search_results
91 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m333400415/?ref=search_results
92 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m222574675/?ref=search_results
93 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m916567471/?ref=search_results
94 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m516644163/?ref=search_results
95 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m30663599997/?ref=search_results
96 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m935881167/?ref=search_results
97 https://www.mercari.com//us/item/m645603485/?ref=search_results
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother @Samsul Islam. I applied you suggestion, and it worked.